# Node.js automatically downgrades when creating a new repository

Tags: javascript, node.js

One of my colleagues has an issue with Node.js 14.8 : when she creates a new repo the node version automatically downgrades to 10.x for some reason.

She has to update it back to v14 every time.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the version that you are declining globally. If you do the update process globally, you will not have such a problem.

Comment: thank you i'll try to reinstall it globally